# C: setenv implicit declaration

Tags: c, declaration, implicit, setenv

For a school project we have to improve a bash-like prompt. Amongst other things, we have to implement the Linux's "cd" command. The only thing we are missing is to change the content of $OLDPWD (so we can use "cd -"). The thing is we keep getting a "implicit declaration of function 'setenv'" (because we need to use that function to update the value of said environment variable), even thought we have included stdlib.h, supposedly the only thing we need for it to work. As a side note, we also can't use unsetenv.

Has this happenned to someone else? Did we overlook something obvious? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon. You need to show an MCVE ([MCVE]) and the compilation command. I suspect you should use `-std=gnu11` instead of `-std=c11`, or otherwise enable POSIX declarations.

Comment: Before `#include <stdlib.h>`, you need to define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to be 200112L or greater, or define `_BSD_SOURCE`. See [setenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html) and [feature_test_macros(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html).

Comment: Yes, i thought i said it in the post but forgot. Editing now

Comment: @IanAbbott Will try that, didn't know i had to do something like that. Thanks!

Comment: @IanAbbott it worked! Thank you very much. As a note, "_BSD_SOURCE" is deprecated, but it works defining "_DEFAULT_SOURCE".

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks for that. I am almost certain I have used *`setenv()`* before and even in the current project and yet somehow I missed that note (because I’m used to it being at before the *`#include`* in the man pages; I've seen it where it is for *`setenv()`* but I had just seen a similar issue for *`strptime()`* (neither necessary for macOS and I am certain too that I tested *`strptime()`* the other day on this specific Linux box). I got an error with *`_POSIX_C_SOURCE`* (running out of space here here so won't include) but then got the message Jaime got; #defining the other works fine.